# How to implement client-side tracing for SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, client-side, trace

I am familiar with server-side tracing for SQL Server, where trace records are written by server to file. What I would like to know is how to reproduce with `System.Data.SqlClient` what SQL Server Profiler does.

Apparently, SQL Server Profiler uses client-side tracing that does not involve creating any trace files on server. Spying on Profiler shows that it passes `NULL` instead of trace file name when it creates the trace:

```
exec sp_trace_create @p1 output,1,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

By the way, [passing NULL filename to sp_trace_create is not documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190362.aspx).

I suppose Profiler keeps the connection open and reads incoming trace records from it. Is this documented anywhere, officially or otherwise?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace` namespace?

Comment: @Martin Smith, not in detail, no. Don't want to FUD, but I seem to recall some discouraging limitations it had, like not being distributed with Express or something.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a bit more searching reveals this helpful piece on [undocumented options of sp_trace_create and the rowset provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx). Doh...